# Strange commands on FTP logs

Tags: linux, security, plesk

I'm battling with WordPress security problems. I have tried everything: my server sends spam by some hacker.

I have checked my FTP log and I found this code

```
/var/www/vhosts/domainname.co.uk/domain.co.uk/img/icons/success.gif b _ d r username ftp 0 * c
```

What does it mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See `man xferlog` for the details but in short:

`/var/www/.../success.gif` is the filename

`b` stands for: a binary transfer

`_` stands for: no special action (like compression or tar) was taken

`d` means that the file is deleted

`r` stands for: access-mode real - a local authenticated user

`username` stands for the authenticated username

`ftp`  stands for the service being invoked

`0` stands for: no authentication-method is used

`*` means that no authenticated-user-id is available

`c` means that the action was completed.

Comment: so the attacker tried to operate those command with the username. username isn't exist but can he access to the server regardless of the username?

Comment: Apparently you have a (FTP) user with that name because of the `r` in the log line stating that a 'real' user is authenticated instead of an anonymous session. Can you elaborate on the actual username in your log line? Did you masquerade the actual username with `username`? The FTP service might be configured to use another user database than `/etc/passwd`, You might have to look into the FTP service configuration.